# Create custom objects from outside of salesforce

Tags: metadata

Is it possible to create a new object from outside of salesforce?
The little bit of research i had done suggests MetaData API should be the way to go?

Any other thoughts
If somebody has done something like this using python, could the code be shared

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Workbench](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench). I think it is PHP based, but it gives you easy GUI access to the Metadata API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the metadata API will allow this ( The Force.com IDE uses this this under the hood to carry out it's operations).

You will need the Metadata API enabled in your org for the user you are logging in as however.

Comment: So my guess this can be achieved from any application

Comment: Any custom APP you choose to build which can talk to the SF metadata API, you should be able to build this functionality in to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Eclipse with the Salesforce plugin. You can copy an existing object, modify it, then upload the new object to Salesforce. Objects are defined using XML so they are human readable.

Comment: Thanks Vin, How does Eclipse create internally? MetadataAPI?

Comment: Yeah, Internally eclipse also uses the metadata to create the Custom Object